# Get the names of multiple columns for sorting in Datatables in Asp.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I need to implement a way to get the list with the names of all the columns for sorting in the jquery datatables plugin. Currently, this only captures the name of the first column that should be sorted.

```
var sortingColumnName = Request.Form.GetValues("columns[" + Request.Form.GetValues("order[0][column]")?[0] + "][name]")?[0];
```

I can not set the string to `Request.Form.GetValues`.

I need this case, for example.:

```
"order": [[2, "asc"], [4, "desc"], [3, "desc"]]
```

When you inspect the elements you can verify that in this example there are three keys to order, **but there may be other cases where you have more or fewer keys**.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `Request.Form`.  The issue you're currently having is that you're trying to manually deserialize posted data into some kind of usable data structure.  The model binding in ASP.NET MVC already does exactly that.

A model structure that works for DataTables would look something like this:

```
public class DataTablesRequestViewModel
{
    public int draw { get; set; }
    public int start { get; set; }
    public int length { get; set; }
    public IList<DataTablesOrder> order { get; set; } = new List<DataTablesOrder>();

    public class DataTablesOrder
    {
        public int column { get; set; }
        public string dir { get; set; }
    }
}
```

You can modify/extend/etc. as you need, but the default posted structure for DataTables should match this.  Simply accept this model on your controller action:

```
public ActionResult YourActionMethod(DataTablesRequestViewModel request)
{
    // in here you can get the list of sorted columns from: request.order
}
```

Comment: Great. I only found one problem: I need the name of the column and not its position (in DataTablesOrder class). It's possible?

Comment: @LeomardeSouza: Not that I know of, unless there's some customization within DataTables to modify what's sent to the server.

Comment: I added a new property to capture all the columns. From the position defined in DataTablesOrder (column) I get the name of the column. That solves my problem. If you would like to supplement the answer with this information, please feel free to. Thank you very much :)

Comment: how you get the column name?

Comment: @rtraees: What do you mean?  The client-side plugin in this case is by default sending the column position as a number.  But server-side you know which positions map to which columns in the query, so you can map the to a column name as needed.  If you have a specific attempt which isn't working in a specific way, you can ask a question here on Stack Overflow.